Оцените архитектуру веб-приложения
Хочу написать приложения и чтобы в дальнейшем не мучатся с переписыванием, решил сейчас накидать схему архитектуры. Очень хотелось бы узнать мнение, касательно того не стоит ли что-то поправить в логике работы.


А Redis не должен перед PostgreSQL стоять, чтобы выступать для неё кэшем? Или тут другая задумка?

согласен с предыдущим комментарием - кеширование данных у вас для чего? для celery, для db или просто так, чтобы было?

Спасибо. Вы правы, поправил. А что насчёт записи логов? Я вот если честно, очень не уверен что собираю логи именно с тех сервисов, с которых нужно.

@mrgervant ну вообще не должен, потому что, во-первых, Redis не умеет отправлять запросы в PostgreSQL (то есть чисто технически сейчас нарисована чушь), а во-вторых, в Redis можно хранить далеко не только данные из базы (но и те же таски из Celery например). Я на одном своём сайте храню в редисе обработанный html, капчу, сессии и рейт-лимиты — ничего из этого не имеет отношения к базе

Клиентов сколько ? Если меньше 1000 запросов в минуту - выкинь это всё

@andreymal Что касается идеи хранения в редис, тасков - спасибо, возьму на вооружения. Что касается связи редис и постгрес, идея такая: пользователь запрашивает у джанго данные хранящиеся в бд, джанго сначала смотрит есть ли эти данные в редис, если есть, забирает от туда, если нет идет в постгрес, берёт данные, отдает их пользователю и сохраняет копию запрошенных данных в редисе. То что сейчас нарисовано, действительно, не верно. Сейчас поправлю чтобы это в большей мере соответствовало реальности.

@eri В ТЗ, как раз и стоит задача: "Приложение должно быть способно обслуживать до 1000 одновременных пользователей в пиковые периоды." - вообще, наверное, я соглашусь что это немного перебор, но тут скорее показан план максимум, чтобы понимать куда потом двигаться, ну а как обеспечить минимум я и сам знаю.

А вообще, кстати, подобным образом выглядит по сути любой сайт, все однажды приходят к чему-то такому в процессе естественной эволюции и без всяких переписываний. Однако если предполагается высокая нагрузка, то здесь напрашивается как минимум один вопрос - а что делать, если PostgreSQL станет обрабатывать запросы слишком медленно и даже кэш Redis перестанет спасать?

Кстати ещё насчёт кэша - между "берёт данные" и "сохраняет копию в редисе" данные в базе могут успеть измениться, что создаёт риск того, что в кэше окажутся старые данные. Если при низкой нагрузке такое будет случаться примерно никогда, то при высокой - примерно всегда, и придётся придумывать, как это предотвратить или хотя бы снизить вредное влияние

Ну Kafka тут явно перебор. У вас что там, миллионы сообщений планируются? Попроще что-нибудь возьмите )

@andreymal касательно PostgreSQL которой не справляется, говорят, что партицирование помогает. Но сам я этим не занимался, поэтому точно не скажу. А что касается кэша в редис, вы абсолютно правы. Этот приём подойдёт не всегда. Но в целом, если данные не обновляются раз в минуту, то метод действенный (проверено на собственном опыте)

@CrazyElf например?

rabbitmq или очереди в том же редисе

@eri Спасибо. Подумаю, как это организовать.
